# 2 Count in 1 sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

ProductTable

```
ProductID   ProductDesc
401         Hotdog
402         Ham
403         Bacon
```

OrderTable

```
OrderID   OrderPayment    NumOrder     OrderDate
5001      Cash            3            9-15-2013
5002      Credit          2            9-16-2013
5003      Credit          2            9-17-2013
5004      Cash            3            9-18-2013
```

OrderDetailsTable

```
OrderDetailsID   OrderID   ProductID
70001            5001      401         -
70002            5001      401         -
70003            5001      403         -
70004            5002      401
70005            5002      402
70006            5003      402
70007            5003      403
70008            5004      403         -
70009            5004      402         -     
70010            5004      401         -
```

How I will count the ProductID on how many it was order by cash on each date and then get the total count of each product?

Sample Output

```
ProductID   ProductDesc   CountOnCash    OrderDate
401         Hotdog        2              9-15-2013
401         Hotdog        1              9-18-2013
401         Hotdog        3              ---------
402         Ham           1              9-18-2013
402         Ham           1              ---------
403         Bacon         1              9-15-2013
403         Bacon         1              9-18-2013
403         Bacon         2              ---------


Select p.ProductID, p.ProductDesc, count(p.ProductId) as NumOrder, o.OrderDate
from Product p
inner join OrderDetails od on p.productid = od.productid
inner join Order o on o.orderid = od.orderid
where orderpayment = 'cash'
Group by p.ProductID, p.ProductDesc, o.OrderDate
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? I see a SQL query. What's the problem with it?

Comment: I think he's asking how to get that subtotal row that combines all the dates. In MySQL it would be `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`, I don't know if TSQL has that.

Comment: it looks like it does: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
GROUP BY p.ProductID, p.ProductDesc, o.OrderDate WITH ROLLUP
```

See the [Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

The subtotal lines will have `NULL` in place of the `OrderDate`. There will also be subtotals for each `ProductID` and for the entire query. You can filter these out with a `HAVING` clause or with code in the application that makes the `SQL` call. Add to the end of the query:

```
HAVING p.ProductDesc IS NOT NULL
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/790c1/9)

Comment: +1 . . . You might have a better interpretation of the question.

Comment: That's essentially what you want, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. But how I will remove those null productdesc. I tried this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/790c1/7

Comment: I told you in the answer: use HAVING.

Comment: How I will filter i with its subtotal? `where CountOnCash = 3`

Comment: Whenever you want to do something with a SELECT result, you have to use HAVING, not WHERE. This is basic SQL. WHERE only operates on the original table data.

Answer (score 1):

You want conditional summation, so move the condition from the `where` clause to a `case` statement:

```
Select p.ProductID, p.ProductDesc,
       sum(case when orderpayment = 'cash' then 1 else 0 end) as NumCash,
       count(*) as NumOrder, o.OrderDate
from Product p
inner join OrderDetails od on p.productid = od.productid
inner join Order o on o.orderid = od.orderid
Group by p.ProductID, p.ProductDesc, o.OrderDate
```

Comment: This is what I thought he was asking for at first, but looking at his example output, I don't think it is. See my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to have subtotals.

```
Select p.ProductID, p.ProductDesc, count(p.ProductId) as NumOrder, o.OrderDate
from Product p
inner join OrderDetails od on p.productid = od.productid
inner join Order o on o.orderid = od.orderid
where orderpayment = 'cash'
Group by p.ProductID, p.ProductDesc, o.OrderDate

Union

Select p.ProductID, p.ProductDesc, count(p.ProductId) as NumOrder, '------'
from Product p
inner join OrderDetails od on p.productid = od.productid
inner join Order o on o.orderid = od.orderid
where orderpayment = 'cash'
Group by p.ProductID, p.ProductDesc
```

will get you the data.